# Android add image as background of text in multiline pdf

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I have to display questions and answers parallel in pdf based on data coming from web service. All dynamic data contain dynamic length. If question as well as answer is very lengthy, then I have to compare both's length & accordingly draw background image & display the data in next line. My question is how to draw the background in multi-line questions and answers? The background is required to be drawn on alternate questions.